# Adding multiple rows to JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

This is a pretty newbie question, but I'm having a difficult time adding multiple rows to a Jtable.

I have a program which reads data from a file that the user has searched for, and I would like to output it all on a table.

The problem is, whenever there is multiple items that match that search, the information doesn't come outputted all on one table, rather the popup menu comes up multiple times, each time displaying just one row on the Jtable, instead of giving me just one popup that will have all the rows in one Jtable.

Here is the code:

```
for (int x=0;x<data.length(); ++x)
            {
                if (database[4].equalsIgnoreCase(valenceInput))                                                                                  //Search database for the number inputted by user
                {

                    Object[][] rows = {                                                                                       
                            {database[0],database[1],database[2],database[3],database[4]}               
                        };

                    Object[] cols = {
                            "Name","Symbol","Atomic Number","Atomic Mass", "# of Valence Electrons"
                        };
                    JTable table = new JTable(rows, cols);

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(table));

                    found=true;                                                                                                                        //Booleon set to true to ensure desired output
                    break;
                }
            }
```

This is what the output comes up as:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvECD.png

Directly after this, I will get another popup which will display another row of data that matched the search, I'm trying to figure out how to put all the rows on one Jtable instead of it showing me many each with just 1 row of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build the `TableModel` within the `for-loop` and show the table once it's done...

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(
    new Object[]{"Name","Symbol","Atomic Number","Atomic Mass", "# of Valence Electrons"},
    0);
for (int x=0;x<data.length(); ++x)
{
    if (database[4].equalsIgnoreCase(valenceInput))                                                                                  //Search database for the number inputted by user
    {
        Object[] rows = {database[0],database[1],database[2],database[3],database[4]};
        model.addRow(rows);
    }
}

JTable table = new JTable(model);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(table));
```

See [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details